# SVN repo issue with linux

Tags: linux, svn, kali-linux, visualsvn, subclipse

I have an svn server *(Hosted in windows server, local server for backup)*, if I connect to that server from windows system it is connecting but Linux system I can't able to access that Repo, recently I changed my OS from Windows to Linux, how can I resolve it,

Using **Spring Tool Suite** with **subclipse** plugin not able to connect to repo it is showing error [(Error message screenshot added here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIQpo.png).

and if I try to access that repo by web page URL from there it is not connecting to the server!

Comment: Configure it accordingly. Does `webserver` actually resolve to the server you want to connect to? Check using `ping` or similar means. If it doesn't setup a suiting entry or change the configuration.

Comment: no, i can't even access that server :(

Comment: If you can't resolve the name to the IP of the server you will have to fix your setup. Setup a hosts entry, tried to append the name etc.

Comment: I can access that repo from browser now, by IP address, but if I enter same IP and repo in eclipse or STS it is not taking, IDE shows loading icon and stuck for a while

Comment: What did you change about your configuration to make it reachable by browser?

Comment: No I didn't changed anything. Just added a static IP address for server then tried with that IP, it came

Comment: In which case you changed from using a DNS name to an IP. What happens "after a while"? Do you use a proxy? If so try to find a way to tell eclipse about it.

Comment: No. DNS still work fine in windows computers. Some Linux computers can access IP, in my PC also IP address ping is working. But something wrong with port maybe